# Django + PostgreSQL на разных серверах: как увеличить скорость?

Tags: django, postgresql

Разрабатываю веб-приложение (Django, python 3, PostgreSQL). В силу определенных требований к приложению необходимо, чтобы БД находилась на другом сервере.

Разница во времени исполнения запросов (одна и та же страница):

- 34,67 ms (29 запросов) - БД и Django на одном и том же сервере
- 2093,07 ms (30 запросов) - БД и Django на разных серверах

SQL данные по django-debug-toolbar

**Вопрос: есть ли способ увеличить скорость трансфера данных?**

Очевидно, основная проблема именно в удаленном подключении. PostgreSQL 9.3, Ubuntu 14.04 (на обоих серверах). Настройки PostgreSQL на данный момент стандартные, разрешено удаленное подключение по логину-паролю.

Comment: Коммутируемое подключение по модему 300 бод? Что-то шустро больно.

Comment: Ping между серверами какой? В одной сети сервера находятся?

Comment: Сервера в разных сетях. Django - в Киеве, БД в Амстердаме.
Результат пинга:
64 bytes from <...>: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=38.5 ms

Comment: Вас может спасти репликация базы данных. А может и нет. Django работает как прежде с локальной базой. Но локальная база периодически синхронизируется с удалённой.

Comment: ИМХО, при таком пинге и такой схеме Вас спасет только кэширование. Можно конечно попробовать поднять VPN, но сокрее всего канал узкий между серверами.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте пробросить порт с одного сервера на другой. Из [документации](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssh-tunnels.html) :

`ssh -L 63333:localhost:5432 joe@foo.com`
где joe - имя пользователя на удаленном сервере foo.com
после чего проверяете на хосте приложения:

`psql -h localhost -p 63333 postgres`

Если пробросить порт не получится, попробуйте хотя бы отключить логирование имен хостов с которых подключаетесь к БД.

`log_hostname = off` в `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Какие основания полагать, что ssh увеличит скорость postgres-у?

Comment: Я думаю, что проблема в установке соединения. Ну и к тому же я уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой, в момент разработки нужно было ходить на удаленный сервер pg.

Comment: Странно всё это. Если конечно не настроен где-то на пути шейпер, который нарочно тормозит весь трафик, кроме "стандарта". А для пущего ускорения можно ещё и сжатие ssh попробывать включить.

Comment: К сожалению, не особо помогло. Примерно те же показатели, может лишь немного быстрее.

Comment: Хотя нет, помогло - время уменьшилось в 1.5 раза. Вместо 2 секунд 1.3 теперь. Но все равно достаточно долго.

Comment: @artbataev но ведь через psql локально исполняются запросы так же быстро?  Если медленнее - сделайте EXPLAIN ANALYZE запроса, там будет видно на что больше всего времени потратилось. Попробуйте залогировать на сервере от самого запроса и до открытия соединения сколько времени проходит

Comment: Писал: 34,67 ms (29 запросов) - БД и Django на одном и том же сервере, 2093,07 ms (30 запросов) - БД и Django на разных серверах. Одна и та же страница, одни и те же данные. Проблема в том, что гонять данные получается безумно дорого.

Comment: без django. просто подключитесь к БД консольной утилитой и сделайте EXPLAIN ANALYZE одного из этих 30 запросов. В двух или трех разные конфигурациях, через интернет, через интернет с выключенным разрешением имени и с проброшенным портом.

Comment: @DmitryV. если бы проблема была в установке соединения, то параметр `'CONN_MAX_AGE': 600` спас бы отца русской демократии.