# Подключение к удаленной БД Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

Всем привет, нужно подключиться к удаленной бд `PostgreSql` через `IntellijIdea` и `PgAdmin3`, там все одинаково, но никак не могу подключиться.

У меня есть: **ip** удаленного сервера, **логин**, **пароль**.
Также есть **имя бд**, пользователь его **name**, и **пароль**.

Через терминал проделывая все действия вручную, я подключаюсь, но подключаться все время через консоль не очень хочется. Думаю это адекватно использовать соответствующие средства для конекта.

Вот формы для ввода данных для коннекта:

db connect
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ssh tunnel
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настроках конекта в pom.xml есть еще один параметр, *server-url*, но вручную я приконекчуюсь же без него.

Comment: проверьте, можно ли сделать то же самое «вручную»: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466274/178576

Comment: psql: could not connect to server: В соединении отказано
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 63333?

Но вручную пошагово я конекчусь. Могу написать как это делаю.

Comment: telnet-ом тоже не подключается? ни на сервере к порту 5432, ни локально к порту 63333 после запуска туннеля?

Comment: видимо подключилось
Trying<my ip>Connected to<my ip>Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2.
Почему порт сервера 5432 я использую 22, думал 5432 порт для конекта к базе

Comment: опцией `-L локальный-порт:localhost:удалённый-порт` вы создаёте туннель. при обращении к `локальный-порт` на локальной машине (программой telnet или psql или любой иной) будет осуществляться подклчюение к `удалённый-порт` на удалённой машине.

Comment: зачем это нужно? Я через терминал могу подключиться к удаленному серверу, а затем к бд, но через connect в intellijidea не выходит, хотя использую теже данные.
Зачем нужно связывать локальный порт с удаленным, если проблема в другом?

Comment: 1. у вас не получается подключиться с помощью программы intellijidea. 2. я предложил вам для проверки проделать ровно те же действия, которые, насколько я понимаю, проделывает эта программа. 3. если вы считаете, что такая проверка не нужна, то не делайте её.

Comment: Приконектится не получается, если тунель соответствия локальный порт - удаленный порт прокинулся. Использовал: psql -h localhost -p 63333 postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сталкивался с такой же проблемой. Решил следующим образом:
Нужно внести изменения в конфигурационный файл (**postgresql.conf**) по части прослушивания порта **5432** на удаленном сервере:

```
# - Connection Settings

listen_addresses = '*'
```

По умолчанию, сервер баз данных PostgreSQL слушает данный порт только локально (*listen_addresses = 'localhost'*).

При этом, конфигурационный файл **pg_hba.conf** у меня такой:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               ident

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          md5

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               md5

# Others
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0             md5
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `listen_addresses = '*'` — вот это дырища так дырища! изложенным в ответе пользоваться настоятельно не рекомендую.